# Drupal 7: Page Hit Counter for Dynamic Pages (not nodes)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

The Drupal 7 Statistics module is able to track and display total hits (views) per node. However, this only works on static nodes such as /node/123 or /2014/some-node-title. I need to also display a hit counter on the homepage () and on pages that are defined in views rather than as nodes. I cannot find a module that does this. I have tried the following modules so far:

1. Statistics (in core): see above
2. Visitors: shows user and session data, *not* page hits
3. Node View Count: only works for nodes, just like Statistics
4. Counter: appears to only show user and session data, *not* page hits

Does anyone know of a module that can accomplish this? If Statistics can do it, how do I make the block appear on dynamic pages such as ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anil Sagar has an example of using statistics to do this with views (see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48148/how-to-get-visitors-count-of-a-page-created-using-views,) but your question is a bit more broad in terms of all pages as opposed to just views.

Personally, I don't like to rely on the statistics module since I want to cache the page as heavily as possible without bootstrapping Drupal. If you are using Google Analytics, I would recommend the [Google Analytics Counter](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter) module, which I think matches your requirements.

Good luck!

Comment: That should do the trick. I wasn't aware of that module.

I don't particularly like loading the site with this kind of computation, but client requirements being what they are... :)